# set MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH cannot specific new script dir for maya

Tags: python, maya

here is my Maya.env

```
λ cat C:\Users\roroco\Documents\maya\2018\Maya.env
MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH=C:/Users/roroco/OneDrive/maya/script
MAYA_PLUGIN_IN_PATH=C:/Users/roroco/OneDrive/maya/plugin
```

I'm sure my script exist:

```
λ cat C:\Users\roroco\OneDrive\maya\script\ro.py
def init():
    print("prpr")
```

and in maya script editor, my script dir exist in MAYA_PATH_DIR

```
getenv MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH;
// Result: C:/Users/roroco/Documents/maya/projects/default/scripts;C:/Users/roroco/OneDrive/maya/script;C:/Users/roroco/Documents/maya/2018/scripts;C:/Users/roroco/Documents/maya/scripts;C:/Users/roroco/Documents/maya/2018/presets;C:/Users/roroco/Documents/maya/2018/prefs/shelves;C:/Users/roroco/Documents/maya/2018/prefs/markingMenus...
```

but when I `import ro` in script editor, it raise:

```
# Error: ImportError: file <maya console> line 1: No module named ro #
```

I hope I can write my maya script and auto sync to onedrive, how should i do
I don't understand [maya doc](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya/files/Environment-Variables-File-path-variables-htm.html) say i can set MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

My tmp solution is add my script_dir in maya startup script

in C:\Users\roroco\Documents\maya\scripts\userSetup.py, add following code:

```
import imp
import os
imp.load_source("", "c:/users/" + os.environ["USERNAME"] + "/OneDrive/maya/script/userSetup.py")
```

and in my_script_dir/userSetup.py add my_script_dir to sys.path

```
import sys
import os

ro_script = os.path.dirname(__file__)
if ro_script not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, ro_script)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to add python paths to your running maya dynamically with `sys.path.insert` or `sys.path.append`.  You should not need to do anything more elaborate than that; you script should be importable if it's on the sys path.

For what you're trying to do a very common and clean solution is to use maya modules. Modules will allow you to append to the usual search directories, and they support network shares -- so you would add a module (in your maya modules path) and point its scripts directory to your onedrive.   Modules can have their own `userSetup.pys` as well, which is very nice for keeping a clean separation between your code and anything else running on a particular machine.

More on modules [here](https://theodox.github.io/2014/magical_modules#magical_modules) and [here](http://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2012/07/distributing-files-on-Maya-Maya-modules.html).  The docs are [here](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_130A3F57_2A5D_4E56_B066_6B86F68EEA22_htm)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to add your path dynamically through `userSetup.py`.

Make sure you include `PYTHONPATH` in your `Maya.env`:

`PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\roroco\OneDrive\maya\script`

Checking my Windows home setup, I'm using back slashes in `Maya.env`, so you can see if switching helps. Instead of checking `MAYA_PATH_DIR`, check your `sys.path` to see if your directory is there. All Python modules need to be in one of these directories to import it:

```
import sys

for p in sys.path:
    print p
```

You can also copy and paste your path to `os.path.exists` to confirm it really does exist. Sometimes it's the right path but the slashes make it so it doesn't resolve properly.